Are Galois-invariant multisets of algebraic integers ever dense in multisubsets of $\mathbb{R}$?
Fix a positive integer $n$.
The space of multisubsets (of cardinality $n$) of $\mathbb{R}$ is the quotient $\mathbb{R}^n /\!/ S_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the action of $S_n$ given by permuting coordinates. In other words, a multisubset of $\mathbb{R}$ is an unordered $n$-tuple of real numbers. $\mathbb{R}^n /\!/ S_n$ obtains a natural quotient topology from $\mathbb{R}$.
An algebraic integer is a complex number which is the root of some monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Each algebraic integer lies in some finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and all of its Galois conjugates are also algebraic integers. Thus, there is a natural action of the absolute Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ on the set of algebraic integers.
A multiset $\mathcal{S}$ of real algebraic integers is said to be Galois-invariant if, for all $x \in \mathcal{S}$, the orbit of $x$ under the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is contained in $\mathcal{S}$.
The set of Galois-invariant multisets of real algebraic integers of cardinality $n$ is a subset of the space of all multisubsets $\mathbb{R}^n/\!/S_n$, and so we may ask:
Question Is the set of Galois-invariant multisets of real algebraic integers of cardinality $n$ ever dense in the space of multisubsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $n$?

For $n = 1$, the answer is no: the Galois-invariant algebraic integers are precisely the integers, and these are not dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
For $n = 2$, the answer is still no: a Galois-invariant multiset of real algebraic integers always turns out to have the form $\{\frac{1}{2}(a \pm b\sqrt{D})\}$ for $a,b,D$ integers with $D \geq 0$. Thus, for example, $\{10.25,10.25\}$ is not very close to any Galois-invariant multiset of two real algebraic integers.
... I imagine that the answer continues to be no forever! But I don't see an obvious reason why.

Definition clarification: do you consider ${\sqrt2,\sqrt2,-\sqrt2}$ to be Galois-invariant?

Yes, I would consider that to be Galois-invariant.

The answer continues to be no forever.
It's easier to work with the set of ordered $n$-tuples (that is, $\Bbb R^n$ itself). Note that if an $n$-tuple is Galois-invariant and has all elements distinct, then it must be the union of full Galois orbits of algebraic integers; in particular, the sum of its elements must be an integer. In particular, any Galois-invariant $n$-tuple must lie inside the union of planes
$$
M = \biggl( \bigcup_{1\le i<j\le n} E_{i,j} \biggr) \cup \biggl( \bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z} S_k \biggr)
$$
where
$$
E_{i,j} = \bigl\{ (x_1,\dots,x_n)\colon x_i=x_j \bigr\}
\quad\text{and}\quad
S_k = \bigl\{ (x_1,\dots,x_n)\colon x_1+\cdots+x_n=k \bigr\};
$$
and $M$ is a measure-zero closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$. To find specific elements of $\Bbb R^n\setminus M$, note for example that most points of the form $(x,2x,\dots,nx)$ are not in $M$; one such point (for $n\ge2$) is $\bigl( \frac1{n^2}, \frac2{n^2}, \dots, \frac n{n^2} \bigr)$.

Thank you! I'm a bit embarrassed to have missed this, and very grateful for the answer.

No worries—I definitely wouldn't have gotten this without your examples, so it's a team effort :)
